# Javascript: Receive data from input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-apps-script

How can I receive data from input field using JavaScript in Google Scripts App?

Ex: I have an input field on html page with some text typed in, and when I press a button that data should be send to a variable from .gs file for further use.

This is my code:

HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 class="center">
      <b>App Title</b>
    </h1>
    <div class="form-auth">
      <label class="inline">Authorization</label>
      <input class="auth-input" placeholder="Insert Authorization"/>
    </div>
    <button class="btn-default start">Start</button>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $('.start').click(function() {
          alert($('.auth-input').val());
        });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

GS:

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
      .createMenu('Menu')
      .addItem('Show sidebar', 'showSidebar')
      .addToUi();
}

function showSidebar() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('login')
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
      .setTitle('SDR Tag Governance')
      .setWidth(300);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
      .showSidebar(html);
}

function getValue() {
  //add the value from input field to a variable
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add an event for example on enter key pressed and pas the value in the function. For example getValue($('.auth-input').val()). Of course you need to change the definition of getValue to: function getValue(val) { }

Comment: In the gs code define the following function: function getValue(val) {
  //do whatever you want with the value for ex show it:
   alert(val); }. Then in your html part change  $('.start').click(function() {
          google.script.run.getValue($('.auth-input').val());
        });

Comment: Also take a look at this page for further info https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run